# Include dropdown menu for side menus with icons

Tags: html, sass

I have this topbaricons ,located at right side of my navbar , i want to include dropdown menu along with this for alerts and message. How can i include it.

```
  <div class="topbaricons" >
        <img class = "alertTorq" src="assets/icons/alerts_torq.png"> 
        <img class = "alertMessage" src="assets/icons/messages_torq.png" >    
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

i believe you can find the answer you need here:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp